# Wordpress: Jquery submit event, page reloading instead of firing a document.location.href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

So, I have a jQuery submit event handler, that on submit queries a database, and if no records are returned, prevents the form page from reloading, and if records were found, should then redirect the user to another page using document.location.href.

But what is actually happening is that records are being found, and instead of then redirecting the user to another page, the form page itself reloads.

What am I overlooking here?

```js
jQuery('#MyForm').submit(function(e) {
  console.log("getUserIDs is successfully hit.");
  alert("The submit event has been hit");
  var countryVal;
  var cityVal;
  var townVal;
  var categoriesVal;
  var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();
  var url = window.location.hostname;

  countryVal = jQuery("#CountryList").val();
  cityVal = jQuery("#CityList").val();
  townVal = jQuery("#TownList").val();
  if (typeof townVal == 'object') {
    townVal = "object";
  }
  categoriesVal = jQuery("#CategoriesList").val();

  jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      action: "showcountries",
      makeselection: "getUserIDs",
      countryID: countryVal,
      cityID: cityVal,
      townID: townVal,
      categoriesID: categoriesVal,
      locationHref: url,
      serialized
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Success of the submit event has been hit.");
      localStorage.setItem('dataObjectTemp2', JSON.stringify(data));
      var numericRecCount = parseInt(data.c);
      jQuery.post('', function(data) {
        document.location.href = window.location.hostname + '/index.php/anotherpage/';
      });
    },
    error: function(data, status, error) {
      alert("No records were returned for your search. Please make another selection.");
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="MyForm" method="Post">
  <input type="submit" name="fl-button" id="fl-button" role="button" value="SEARCH" class="fl-button" disabled="disabled" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is the alert coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#MyForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var countryVal;
    var cityVal;
    var townVal;
    var categoriesVal;
    var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();
    var url = window.location.hostname;

    countryVal = jQuery("#CountryList").val();
    cityVal = jQuery("#CityList").val();
    townVal = jQuery("#TownList").val();

    if (typeof townVal == 'object') {
        townVal = "object";
    }
    categoriesVal = jQuery("#CategoriesList").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
        data: serialized + '&action=showcountries&makeselection=getUserIDs&countryID=' +
                countryVal + '&cityID=' + cityVal + '&townID=' + townVal + '&categoriesID=' +
                categoriesVal + '&locationHref=' + url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
            localStorage.setItem('dataObjectTemp2', JSON.stringify(data));
            var numericRecCount = parseInt(data.c);

            window.location.href = url + '/index.php/anotherpage/';
        },
        error: function (data, status, error) {
            alert("No records were returned for your search. Please make another selection.");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   jQuery('#MyForm').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //use prevent default here
      console.log("getUserIDs is successfully hit.");
      alert("The submit event has been hit");
      var countryVal;
      var cityVal;
      var townVal;
      var categoriesVal;
      var serialized = jQuery('#MyForm').serialize();
      var url = window.location.hostname;

      countryVal = jQuery("#CountryList").val();
      cityVal = jQuery("#CityList").val();
      townVal = jQuery("#TownList").val();
      if (typeof townVal == 'object'){
          townVal = "object";
      }
      categoriesVal = jQuery("#CategoriesList").val();

      jQuery.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: gymRegions.ajaxurl,
        data:{action: "showcountries",
          makeselection: "getUserIDs",
          countryID: countryVal,
          cityID: cityVal,
          townID: townVal,
          categoriesID: categoriesVal,
          locationHref: url,
          serialized},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success of the submit event has been hit.");
            localStorage.setItem('dataObjectTemp2', JSON.stringify(data));
            var numericRecCount = parseInt(data.c);

            document.location.href = window.location.hostname + '/index.php/anotherpage/';

      },
      error: function (data, status, error) {
          alert("No records were returned for your search. Please make another selection.");
          console.log(data);
          console.log(status);
          console.log(error);
      }
  });
});
```